# Class Methods in Text Adventure with Branching Storyline

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment that involves creating a text adventure with a branching story line.

It works like this:

- Level 1 has 1 prompt and 3 choices
- Level 2 has 3 prompts and 9 choices
- Level 3 has 9 prompts and 27 choices
- Level 4 has 27 prompts and 81 choices

Each choice taken leads to a new and unique prompt on the next level with 3 more choices.

I have a basic class set up like this:

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self,level_num, level_prompt):
        self.level_num = level_num
        self.level_prompt = level_prompt
        self.choices = []

    def add_choices(self, choices, next_branch):
        self.choices.append(choices)
        self.next_branch = next_branch

    def print_situation(self):
        print("Level " + str(self.level_num))
        print(self.level_prompt)
        print("[A] " + self.choices[0])
        print("[B] " + self.choices[1])
        print("[C] " + self.choices[2])
```

And I am initializing the levels starting off like this:

```
level1 = Level(1, 'PROMPT HERE')
level1.add_choices('CHOICE A', '2_A')
level1.add_choices('CHOICE_B', '2_B')
level1.add_choices('CHOICE_C', '2_C')

level2_A = Level(2, 'PROMPT HERE')
level2_A.add_choices('CHOICE A', '3_A1')
level2_A.add_choices('CHOICE_B', '3_A2')
level2_A.add_choices('CHOICE_C', '3_A3')

level2_B = Level(2, 'PROMPT HERE')
level2_B.add_choices('CHOICE A', '3_B1')
level2_B.add_choices('CHOICE_B', '3_B2')
level2_B.add_choices('CHOICE_C', '3_B3')

level2_C = Level(2, 'PROMPT HERE')
level2_C.add_choices('CHOICE A', '3_C1')
level2_C.add_choices('CHOICE_B', '3_C2')
level2_C.add_choices('CHOICE_C', '3_C3')
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to associate each choice made with the next "level". I have the "next_branch" argument in the "add_choices" method but I'm having trouble figuring out how to follow up with that.

How I want it to work is, during level 1, you choose A, so then the program will print the prompt and choices associated with "level2_A". Keep in mind this will have to support a ton of separate choices and prompts in the later levels, so I'm trying to find an efficient way to manage the branching storyline.

Let me know if anything isn't clear..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The typical way in Python to associate pairs of things together is by using a dictionary. In this case the `add_choices()` method could add an entry to such a dictionary by something like `self.mapping_dict[choices] = next_level` each time it was called (assuming a `self.mapping_dict = {}` was executed in the class `__init__()` method to initially create an empty dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a string "2_A" to the method, you could define the level2_A instance *first* and then pass the object directly to the method:

```
level1 = Level(1, "PROMPT HERE")
level2_A = Level(2, "PROMPT HERE")

level1.add_choices("CHOICE A", level2_A)
```

In this scenario, you would define all of your levels first, and then define how they are related to one another.

With exponential growth like this, your game will quickly get very massive. You might find it easier to store the definitions in a data file, and construct the level objects automatically by loading data from the file. This would separate your content from your game logic and make things easier to work with. Something to think about!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have any idea how to orchestrate the story line by any chance? I want to refrain from writing 100 nested if statements (if choice = a then print level2_A) for example.

Comment: I would store the text of each level in a property of the level itself. When you run the level, display the story segment, then prompt the user for their choice. You can then just call the print_situation() method for the corresponding level.

Comment: That way, your functionality is contained within the class and separated from your content.

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot.